# Iterate and execute through CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In `@proc_name` table variable, I have stored procedure name and I am passing parameters using dynamic SQL. I am using a while loop to loop through all rows in `@proc_name`. Can I use a CTE here to improve performance?

```
SELECT * 
FROM @proc_name

WHILE (@count <= @max)
BEGIN
    SET @proc_exec = 'usp_Balance_'
        +Replace((SELECT Description FROM @proc_name WHERE rn= @count),' ','')+' '+' '+''''
        +Replace((SELECT TellerID FROM @proc_name WHERE rn= @count),' ','')+''''+' ,'+''''
            +@LocationID+''''+' , '+''''+cONvert(VARCHAR(100),@BusinessDate)+''''

    -- Update TDrawerSummary
    PRINT (@proc_exec) 

    SET @count = @count + 1
END
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably not going to be able to improve this much, but a bit difficult to completely understand.  Are you positive you need the `dynamic sql` to run the stored procedure over each recordin `@proc_name`?  What actually happens in that stored proc?

Comment: CTEs (in SQL Server) don't improve performance.  They do make queries easier to understand, t hough.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've had them improve performance -- select a small set of fields from a large table which are unique and contained in an index in the cte and then join back to the table to get rest of the columns.

Comment: At the very least change this to use a cursor instead of doing two selects for every iteration of the loop -- that will make the loop processing twice as fast.  (Won't improve the time taken to make the function call.)

Comment: @Hogan . . . SQL Server processes CTEs by substituting the code directly into the query -- much like the processing for views.  SQL Server does prune columns when it reads from a table.  However, it does not materialize CTEs or have other special optimizations (as far as I know, although the newest versions may have done something).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Ok if you know the internals of SQL optimization to be sure -- I've def. seen an effect on DB2 but I don't ever *specifically* seeing it on SQL Server.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Most databases do materialize CTEs, at least sometimes.  SQL Server does not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server never does?  I think DB2 sometimes does and sometimes does not.

Comment: @Hogan . . . There is not even a compiler hint to force materialization.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, replace the WHILE loop by a cursor as shown below:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 'usp_Balance_'
            +Replace(Description,' ','')+' '+' '+''''
            +Replace(TellerID,' ','')+''''+' ,'+''''
                +@LocationID+''''+' , '+''''+cONvert(VARCHAR(100),@BusinessDate)+''''
    FROM @proc_name
    ORDER BY rn
OPEN c
FETCH c INTO @proc_exec
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        -- Update TDrawerSummary
        PRINT @proc_exec
        FETCH c INTO @proc_exec
    END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

In some cases you could use a CTE to help convert procedural code into a query. This could improve performance. If you can share the code that is building @proc_name I could check if there is a possibility for this.

Inside the cursor you should consider to take some measures that will help you track down errors. In the current code, it will be quite hard to know in which iteration an error happened. A simplified example is shown below:

```
    BEGIN TRY
        -- Update TDrawerSummary
        PRINT @proc_exec
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Failed executing '+COALESCE(@proc_exec,'(null)')+': '+ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Very nice code example of my suggestion.  Good answer!